# Android Location for getting countryCode

Tags: android, location

I want to get the country code based on my device's current location. I have used a `LocationListener` as follows:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationListener = new LocationListener() { 

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    makeUseOfNewLocation(location); 
}

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

... but it takes a long time to return the location.

How can I get the country code faster?

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried so far....

Comment: locationManager =
    (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  locationListener = new LocationListener() {
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
   }

Comment: locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the GPS provider, then you may need to wait for a GPS signal. Given that you're only trying to determine the country, the `NETWORK_PROVIDER` should provide sufficient granularity, and should give you a much quicker response.

You can also get a faster fix on your location by using the last known location:

```
Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
```

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#FastFix

Answer (score 0):

Instead of location, maybe you should use  [Locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html)?

For example:
Country code:

```
Locale.getDefault().getCountry
```

Language code:

```
 Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()
```

Hope it's helps.

Comment: thanks for reply but it have some issues.like it return the device manufacturer country code not the current....